# Google Spreadsheet; Function to Search a Sheet for String and Return Value of Next Column

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Here is what I have so far. it will:

1. Search for keyword in my other sheet (JSON)
2. When it finds the keyword (modname) it returns the row #

The keyword is on the A column. What I want is for a function to return the ***value* on the *B column* of the same row.** How do I do this?

```
function onSearch2(modname)
{
    var searchString = modname;
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("JSON164"); 
    var column =1; //column Index   
    var columnValues = sheet.getRange(2, column, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); //1st is header row
    var searchResult = columnValues.findIndex(searchString); //Row Index - 2

    if(searchResult != -1)
    {
        //searchResult + 2 is row index.
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().setActiveRange(sheet.getRange(searchResult + 2, 1))
        return searchResult+2
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the spreadsheet with us? Or perhaps include a portion of it in your answer? It will make it easier to understand your problem.

Comment: Duncan, just post your solution as an answer to your own question.

Comment: See: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was working on a solution as well.

### Code

```
function onSearch1(searchString) {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("JSON164");
  var values = sh.getDataRange().getValues();

  for(var i=0, iLen=values.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if(values[i][0] == searchString) {
      return values[i][1];
    }
  }     
}
```

### Explained

The value *var* will retrieve all values at once. The single result *var* will capture the first index found in the range. After that, the result of the adjacent column will be shown, analogue to *values[i][0]*.

### Usage

```
=onSearch1("test")
```

### Note

The findIndex function is none-exsisting in Google Apps Script. If you want to seperate them, then use this code:

```
function onSearch2(searchString) {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("JSON164");
  var values = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var i = findIndex(values, searchString);

  return values[i][1]; 
}

function findIndex(values, searchString) {
  for(var i=0, iLen=values.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if(values[i][0] == searchString) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}
```

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[findIndex](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdEc0WWg5SzJHbUJQbmxsd2NUcEtJWnc&usp=sharing)**

Comment: Thanks this one is good too. Here is what I ended up using in OP

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question correctly, you want to search a column for a specific string, and if found, return a value from another column in the same row.

Here's my suggestion:

```
var SPREADSHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";
var SEARCH_COL_IDX = 1;
var RETURN_COL_IDX = 0;

function searchStr(str) {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SPREADSHEET_NAME).getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str) {
      return row[RETURN_COL_IDX];
    }
  }
}
```

To use this function from your sheet, simply use the formula `=searchStr(search term)`. I have set up an example spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Avea1NXBTibYdHpacExoUTBsNThkbjhPYVdlTnQwU2c&usp=sharing).

The `SEARCH_COL_IDX` and `RETURN_COL_IDX` constants can be made parameters to the search function, if you like, to make it more generic.

Comment: Thanks this one is good. Here is what I ended up using in OP